# StacklessClosedChannelException caught JavaFlightRecorder

Tags: vert.x

Why such exceptions are happening? What the cause of it?

I caught it using JavaFlightRecorder.

I using AWS EC2 instances and AWS Load Balancer, all traffic coming from balancer and looks like something went wrong

All of it stacktrace starting from:

```
ctx.response().putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())
.end(Buffer.buffer(jsonService.serialize(response)));
```

Full stacktrace:

```
void java.io.IOException.<init>():47
void java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.<init>():53
void io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException.<init>():29
StacklessClosedChannelException io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException.newInstance(Class, String):41
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(ChannelPromise):607
void io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$EmbeddedUnsafe$1.close(ChannelPromise):815
void io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.close(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelPromise):1352
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(ChannelPromise):622
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(ChannelPromise):606
void io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibEncoder$2.operationComplete(ChannelFuture):267
void io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibEncoder$2.operationComplete(Future):264
void io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(Future, GenericFutureListener):578
void io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow():552
void io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners():491
Promise io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(GenericFutureListener):184
ChannelPromise io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(GenericFutureListener):95
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(GenericFutureListener):30
void io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibEncoder.close(ChannelHandlerContext, ChannelPromise):264
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(ChannelPromise):622
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(ChannelPromise):606
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.close(ChannelPromise):994
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(ChannelPromise):268
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.close(ChannelPromise):568
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.close():555
boolean io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.finish(boolean):503
boolean io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.finish():483
void io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.finishEncode(List):341
boolean io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.encodeContent(HttpContent, List):272
void io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.encodeFullResponse(HttpResponse, HttpContent, List):227
void io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.encode(ChannelHandlerContext, HttpObject, List):189
void io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.encode(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, List):56
void io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$1.encode(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, List):67
void io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, ChannelPromise):89
void io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.write(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, ChannelPromise):116
void io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChunkContentCompressor.write(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, ChannelPromise):38
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(Object, ChannelPromise):717
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(Object, ChannelPromise):709
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(Object, boolean, ChannelPromise):792
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(Object, ChannelPromise):702
void io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.doFlush(ChannelHandlerContext):303
void io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.flush(ChannelHandlerContext):132
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0():750
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush():742
ChannelHandlerContext io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush():728
void io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelHandlerContext):127
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0():750
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(Object, ChannelPromise):765
void io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(Object, boolean, ChannelPromise):790
ChannelFuture io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(Object, ChannelPromise):758
void io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.write(Object, Boolean, ChannelPromise):178
void io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(Object, boolean, ChannelPromise):230
void io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(Object, ChannelPromise):215
void io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.writeToChannel(Object, FutureListener):211
void io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.end(Buffer, PromiseInternal):407
Future io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse.end(Buffer):382
```

Comment: It seems the remote peer closed the connection while there were pending writes in the channel.

Answer (score 0):

The machine making the request closed/killed the connection